# Asp.net Masterpage and ContentPage JavaScript Function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, colorbox

I am using a Masterpage for my upload_photo.aspx which displays the file upload page using colorBox. However, ever since i added (code below) in the Masterpage colorBox doesn't display:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#txtAutoCompleteSearch").AutoComplete("search.aspx?searchword=");
            });

            function clear_textbox() {
                if (document.aspnetForm.searchField.value == " Enter Your Search Here ")
                    document.aspnetForm.searchField.value = "";
            };

        </script>
```

Below is the mastpage code:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Css/menu_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="styles/css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        google.load('jquery', '1.3.2');</script>
    <script src="styles/js/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="styles/js/jquery.dimensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="styles/js/jquery.highlight-3.yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtAutoCompleteSearch").AutoComplete("search.aspx?searchword=");
        });

        function clear_textbox() {
            if (document.aspnetForm.searchField.value == " Enter Your Search Here ")
                document.aspnetForm.searchField.value = "";
        };

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="masterPageForm" runat="server">

    <div id="pagewidth">
        <div id="Header">
            <asp:Label ID="userName" runat="server" Text="" style=" color: Maroon; font-size: large; z-index: 103; left: 805px; position: absolute; top: 132px"></asp:Label>
             <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" 
                LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" LogoutText="Logout" CssClass="logOut" 
                BackColor="#454545" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial Black" 
                Font-Size="Small" />

            <%--<asp:Image ID="logoHeader" runat="server" CssClass="rounded-corners" ImageUrl="~/img/logo.png"/>--%>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/logo.png" NavigateUrl="~/home.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>

            <%--style="width: 1000px; height: 120px; margin-top: 10px;" />--%>
            <div style="top: 61px; left: 476px; position: absolute; height: 37px; width: 526px; font-size: medium; font-style: italic; color: #CCFF99; font-weight: bolder; z-index: 103;">
                <input id="txtAutoCompleteSearch" name="searchField" class="tb11" type="text" onfocus="clear_textbox()" value=" Enter Your Search Here "/> 
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Heading" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>

        <div class="background">
   <asp:menu id="NavigationMenu" CssClass="NavigationMenu"  
        staticdisplaylevels="2" DynamicHorizontalOffset="1"
        staticsubmenuindent="1px" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4"
        orientation="Horizontal"   
        DynamicPopOutImageUrl="~/img/right-arrow.gif" 
        StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/img/drop-arrow.gif"
        datasourceid="MenuSource"    
        runat="server" Height="30px">

        <staticmenuitemstyle ItemSpacing="10" CssClass="staticMenuItemStyle"/>
        <statichoverstyle CssClass="staticHoverStyle" />
        <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="staticMenuItemSelectedStyle"/> 
        <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuItemStyle" />      
        <dynamichoverstyle CssClass="menuItemMouseOver" />
        <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="menuItem" />
        <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="menuItemSelected" />

        <DataBindings>        
             <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="siteMapNode" 
                NavigateUrlField="url" TextField="title"  
                    ToolTipField="description" />
        </DataBindings>

      </asp:menu>
    </div>

    <asp:TreeView ID="NavigationTreeView" runat="server" Visible="false" DataSourceID="MenuSource" />

<div id="e">
        <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" 
                RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" 
                CssClass="currentNodeStyle"
            PathSeparator=" >> " Visible="False">
            <PathSeparatorStyle ForeColor="#5D7B9D" CssClass="currentNodeStyle" />
            <CurrentNodeStyle ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="currentNodeStyle" />
            <NodeStyle ForeColor="#7C6F57"  CssClass="currentNodeStyle"  />
            <RootNodeStyle  ForeColor="#5D7B9D" CssClass="currentNodeStyle"  />
    </asp:SiteMapPath> 
</div>    

    <asp:Panel ID="AccessKeyPanel" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
       <asp:SiteMapDataSource id="MenuSource" runat="server" StartFromCurrentNode="false" ShowStartingNode="true" />

       <div id="tabDiv">
             <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="mainBody" runat="server">

             </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>   
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            &copy; Copyright Family Photo Online System</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function navigateTo(url) {
        window.location = url;
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the upload_photo.aspx code for the javascript:

```
<script src="alerts/impromptu/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="alerts/impromptu/jquery-impromptu.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="alerts/impromptu/impromptu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="colorBox/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="colorBox/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="colorBox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
            $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
            $("a[rel='example2']").colorbox({ transition: "fade" });
            $("a[rel='example3']").colorbox({ transition: "none", width: "75%", height: "75%" });
            $("a[rel='example4']").colorbox({ slideshow: true });
            $(".example5").colorbox();
            $(".example6").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 425, innerHeight: 344 });
            $(".example7").colorbox({ width: "47%", height: "100%", iframe: true });
            $(".example8").colorbox({ width: "50%", inline: true, href: "#inline_example1" });
            $(".example9").colorbox({
                onOpen: function () { alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad: function () { alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete: function () { alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup: function () { alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed: function () { alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function () {
                $('#click').css({ "background-color": "#f00", "color": "#fff", "cursor": "inherit" }).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Firebug throws the following error:

$("a[rel='example1']").colorbox is not a function
http://localhost:3478/upload_photo.aspx
Line 19

If I remove the Javascript function from the Masterpage the colorBox jQuery works fine.

Can anyone advice me where I am going wrong and how i can correct it? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: different versions of jquary in master page and upload_photo.aspx. load jquary 1.4.4 on master page and remove the jquary reference from sub pages. hope this will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because you're including jquery both in the master page and in the photo page. This will cause jQuery to load, initialize, run the script in your master page, then throw it all out and reload, reinitialize everything when it hits the script tag for jQuery in the upload_photo.aspx. You only want each javascript library to load once, otherwise all sorts of confusion sets in.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So what would be the best way to do this? apologies for my lack of knowledge.